# How to cast string to complex and nested interface in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vega, vega-lite

I am migrating Javascript to Typescript.

I have the following code from [this npm pacakage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vega).

I want to convert `spec` (as string) to type `VisualizationSpec` so that `<VegaLite spec={spec} data={barData} />,` works.

I tried cast but it does not work. This interface is nested and complex, so I failed.

How to cast string to complex and nested interface in Typescript?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { VegaLite } from 'react-vega'

const spec = {
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  mark: 'bar',
  encoding: {
    x: { field: 'a', type: 'ordinal' },
    y: { field: 'b', type: 'quantitative' },
  },
  data: { name: 'table' }, // note: vega-lite data attribute is a plain object instead of an array
}

const barData = {
  table: [
    { a: 'A', b: 28 },
    { a: 'B', b: 55 },
    { a: 'C', b: 43 },
    { a: 'D', b: 91 },
    { a: 'E', b: 81 },
    { a: 'F', b: 53 },
    { a: 'G', b: 19 },
    { a: 'H', b: 87 },
    { a: 'I', b: 52 },
  ],
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <VegaLite spec={spec} data={barData} />,
  document.getElementById('bar-container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VisualizationSpec` type has indeed complex definition, and few properties like `mark` , `encoding.x.type` expect specific values.

```js
// vega-lite\src\type.d.ts
export declare type StandardType = 'quantitative' | 'ordinal' | 'temporal' | 'nominal';
```

```js
// vega-lite\src\mark.ts
export const Mark = {
  arc: 'arc',
  area: 'area',
  bar: 'bar',
  image: 'image',
  line: 'line',
  point: 'point',
  rect: 'rect',
  rule: 'rule',
  text: 'text',
  tick: 'tick',
  trail: 'trail',
  circle: 'circle',
  square: 'square',
  geoshape: 'geoshape'
} as const;
```

I copied your code, installed necessary npm packages and saw typescript complained about 2 mentioned things.

There are many workarounds. const assertion to specific properties, whole object, you can even explicity specify `spec` is of type `VisualizationSpec` and it still would be fine.

You could also import subtypes and use them. Like `Mark.bar` `'ordinal' as StandardType`

```js
const spec = {
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  mark: "bar" as const,
  encoding: {
    x: { field: 'a', type: 'ordinal' as const },
    y: { field: 'b', type: 'quantitative' as const },
  },
  data: { name: 'table' },
}
```

```js
const spec: VisualizationSpec = {
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  mark: "bar",
  encoding: {
    x: { field: 'a', type: 'ordinal'},
    y: { field: 'b', type: 'quantitative'},
  },
```